# How to reduce loss values in the denoising process of sine signals using deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, loss-function

I have a serials of sine signals which have co frequency noise, I want to remove these noise by using deep learning, and expecting the MSE Loss can be reduced to within 1 while the input and the target are between -100 to 100.

I have tried U-Net++, RIDNet, CBDNet, DnCNN and so on, The input is a series of sinusoidal signals with a size of 32 * 1 * 900, the numerical range is from -100 to 100, and the output have the same size and same numerical range to the input. The loss function adopts Huber Loss.
However, the loss value during training stops decreasing when it reaches 1.3 while my expected loss value is a value less than 1, or make the difference as close to the Gaussian distribution as possible.
How can I reduce this loss value, it seems that my network is already saturated.

An example of my data is shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwWdM.jpg)

```
class DnCNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, channels, num_of_layers=6):
    super(DnCNN, self).__init__()
    kernel_size = 3
    padding = 1
    features = 128
    layers = []
    layers.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels=channels, out_channels=features, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=padding))
    layers.append(nn.GELU())
    for _ in range(num_of_layers-2):
        layers.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels=features, out_channels=features, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=padding))
        layers.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(features))
        layers.append(nn.GELU())
    layers.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels=features, out_channels=channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=padding))
    layers.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels=channels, out_channels=channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=padding))
    self.dncnn = nn.Sequential(*layers)


def forward(self, x):
    f1 = self.dncnn(x)

    return f1
```

Comment: 32 is your batch size ? Could you post your training source code and an example of one data ? I don't understand the use of CNN, Unet for something that looks like 1D data. Could you explain more please ?

Comment: the size of my input data is 1*900, batch size is 32, I have tried 16 and 64, the loss value is seem not going down. I have added an example of my data and my code.

Comment: did you try with another loss function ?